# Как настроить чувстивтельность курсора прокрутки в браузере жестом нажатия на СКМ?

Tags: браузер

Минимальная скорость (когда нажал на СКМ в браузере и опустил мышь на пиксель) слишком высокая. Обыскал параметры яндекса, погуглил, нашёл подходящее мне расширение для автоскролла, но оно не работает на нужном мне сайте. Хочу изменить параметры, но где это можно сделать? Скрипт downarrow с интервалом не так удобен.

Comment: это яндекс браузер, решение нужно именно с ним

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.